# Is a question about sung phonemes on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask "Over what phoneme is overtone singing possible?", but it seems there currently is no question about phonemes in singing.

Should I ask this question on Linguistics SE instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this question would be better here than on linguistics, since it's about singing which is on-topic here and not really on topic there.

The fact that there are no other questions touching upon phonemes merely indicates that we don't need a tag for phonemes.